# Is is possible for .listFiles() to return files in different order on different systems

Tags: java

As a result of processing, some data files are written to disk.

- Count of files between 2 servers (MAC and Linux) match
- File names are identical between systems
- Files content is identical between systems, as measured by md5sum

Report is then computed based on content read from said files, using

```
    for (File f : contentDirectory.listFiles()) {
               // magic
```

`.listFiles()` javadoc says:

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array
>   will appear in any specific order; they are not, in particular,
>   guaranteed to appear in alphabetical order.

While that is true, i wonder ... the order in which files will be listed, is not random, right? I mean, listing same files 2 times will produce the same results is this correct?

Does this mean that when files are listed on 2 different systems, order is likely to not be the same?

**Ultimately the bigger question is, how to list files in a directory in same order regardless of OS file are stored on?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort the files. `File` is comparable so we don't even need a comparator:

```
File[] files = File.listRoots()[0].listFiles();
Arrays.sort(files);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(files));
```

(This example simply takes the files from the first root directory, that should have some content on every computer ;))

*Alternative*

The file objects should be unique so we can create a tree set:

```
for (File file : new TreeSet<File>(Arrays.asList(contentDirectory.listFiles()))) {
    System.out.println(file.getName());  // replace with magic ;)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

They don't give any guarantee of the order.  So don't rely on it.  Even if you can verify that it will work today, it might not work tomorrow.  Or on lists with more than 4K files.  Or some other random criteria you don't know about.

If you want order, that's easy.  Sort the list before iterating over it.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect the order to depend on the implementation details of the local JVM and/or the local filesystem. Most likely, the files are listed in the same order as the filesystem's table of contents for that folder, which may depend on the order in which the files were added to the folder or other such details.

If your program is dependent on the files being in a certain order, your best bet is to get the list of file names, sort them however you like, then open the files. That way, you are not depending on the local implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class File  implements Serializable, Comparable<File>
```

`java.util.Collections.sort()` will therefore work nicely if you dump the files into an List.

Read the release notes for Java 7 and you will see a number of cases where "not guaranteed" changed, and other places where "non-public" api's were removed or changed. If the doc says you can't rely on it you can't rely on it. It could change in any major or minor release.